# get all local IP address Using powershell in txt file. Want to filter MAC address

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to save all active IP address under 192.168.1 subnet mask and there MAC address starts with "00:1f".

This question is already answered but how can I filter using MAC address and save only IP not other information.

[Question] [Use powershell to get device names and their ipaddress on a home network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785413/use-powershell-to-get-device-names-and-their-ipaddress-on-a-home-network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-NetNeighbor` and filter the output with `Where-Object`:

```
Get-NetNeighbor -IPAddress 192.168.1.* |Where-Object LinkLayerAddress -like '00-1F-*' |ForEach-Object IPAddress
```

Comment: yes I did that and it worked.

Comment: I appended to existing command `| out-File -FilePath "IPs.txt"` to save file in current directory.